# Write log in file in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am using .NET 6 and working with ASP.NET Core. My issue is: I want to write logs to a file and and check it but it seems it doesn't have mechanism to write log in file by default and I have to install `serilog` package. So I installed and used it in `program.cs` to override default system for logging:

```
using Serilog;
Log.Information("Starting web application");
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Host.UseSerilog();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Also, I used log in my controller and my problem is it doesn't create any log file and writing log? It just shows up `Doing something...` on console and seems `serilog` doesn't do anything. What is the problem?

This is my controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication5.Models;

namespace WebApplication5.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly ILogger<UserController> _logger;

    public UserController(AppDbContext dbContext, ILogger<UserController> logger)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet("test")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Doing something...");
        List<User> users = await _dbContext.user.ToListAsync();
        return new OkObjectResult(users);
    }
}
```

I am new to C# and I appreciate any tip.

Comment: In your controller, you are using Microsoft Logging API. So you must register/configure your serilog setup with DI.

Comment: Can you add break points and get to the log code?  Are you running on localhost or a remote machine?  You may not have privilege to write to the log.  You can check event viewer to see if there are any errors when the writes occur.

Comment: @Fildor how can i do that?

Comment: ^^ See also: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore Should be as easy as adding `services.UseSerilog();` or very similar and adding a nuget.

Comment: I think you forgot to call [`ConfigureLogging`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider#usage-and-registration-of-the-custom-logger)

Comment: @Fildor i eddited the post but still not works

Comment: As stated [here](https://www.techrepository.in/blog/posts/implementing-logging-in-a-net-core-web-application-using-serilog) you need `.ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.AddSerilog())`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a few packages:

```
Serilog
Serilog.AspNetCore
Serilog.Sinks.File
Serilog.Sinks.Console (if you want console output as well)
```

I just used your controller (a bit modified since I'm missing the db context)

Program.cs (from a plain vanilla Web API project)

```
using Serilog;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

// Logging 

var env = builder.Environment;
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

if (env.IsDevelopment())
{

    builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostContext, services, configuration) => {
        configuration
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.File("serilog-file.txt")
            .WriteTo.Console();
    });
}
else
{
    builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostContext, services, configuration) => {
        configuration
            .WriteTo.File("serilog-file.txt")
            .WriteTo.Console();
    });
}

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

My UserController:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace TestLogging.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        //private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly ILogger<UserController> _logger;

        public UserController(ILogger<UserController> logger)
        {
            //_dbContext = dbContext;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet("test")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Doing something...");
            List<User> users = new();
            users.Add(new User(1,"Bob Chand", "ChandB@aol.com"));
            users.Add(new User(2, "Rick Astley", "AstleyR@rickrolled.com"));
            users.Add(new User(3, "Jerry Right", "JerryNotWrong@gmail.com"));
            _logger.LogDebug(message: $"GetUsers retrieved {JsonSerializer.Serialize(users)}");

            return new OkObjectResult(users);
        }
    }
}
```

Output (Snipped a bit):

```
2023-06-01 10:47:56.143 -04:00 [DBG] Request matched endpoint 'TestLogging.Controllers.UserController.GetUsers (TestLogging)'
2023-06-01 10:47:56.144 -04:00 [DBG] Static files was skipped as the request already matched an endpoint.
2023-06-01 10:47:56.147 -04:00 [INF] Executing endpoint 'TestLogging.Controllers.UserController.GetUsers (TestLogging)'
2023-06-01 10:47:56.160 -04:00 [INF] Route matched with {action = "GetUsers", controller = "User"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] GetUsers() on controller TestLogging.Controllers.UserController (TestLogging).
2023-06-01 10:47:56.163 -04:00 [DBG] Execution plan of authorization filters (in the following order): ["None"]
2023-06-01 10:47:56.164 -04:00 [DBG] Execution plan of resource filters (in the following order): ["None"]
2023-06-01 10:47:56.164 -04:00 [DBG] Execution plan of action filters (in the following order): ["Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ControllerActionFilter (Order: -2147483648)","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.UnsupportedContentTypeFilter (Order: -3000)","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ModelStateInvalidFilter (Order: -2000)"]
2023-06-01 10:47:56.166 -04:00 [DBG] Execution plan of exception filters (in the following order): ["None"]
2023-06-01 10:47:56.166 -04:00 [DBG] Execution plan of result filters (in the following order): ["Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ClientErrorResultFilter (Order: -2000)"]
2023-06-01 10:47:56.167 -04:00 [DBG] Executing controller factory for controller TestLogging.Controllers.UserController (TestLogging)
2023-06-01 10:47:56.168 -04:00 [DBG] Executed controller factory for controller TestLogging.Controllers.UserController (TestLogging)
2023-06-01 10:47:56.212 -04:00 [INF] Executing action method TestLogging.Controllers.UserController.GetUsers (TestLogging) - Validation state: "Valid"
2023-06-01 10:47:56.215 -04:00 [INF] Doing something...
2023-06-01 10:47:56.217 -04:00 [DBG] GetUsers retrieved [{"Id":1,"Name":"Bob Chand","Email":"ChandB@aol.com"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Rick Astley","Email":"AstleyR@rickrolled.com"},{"Id":3,"Name":"Jerry Right","Email":"JerryNotWrong@gmail.com"}]
2023-06-01 10:47:56.221 -04:00 [INF] Executed action method TestLogging.Controllers.UserController.GetUsers (TestLogging), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult in 3.7833ms.
2023-06-01 10:47:56.225 -04:00 [DBG] List of registered output formatters, in the following order: ["Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.HttpNoContentOutputFormatter","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.StringOutputFormatter","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.StreamOutputFormatter","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter"]
2023-06-01 10:47:56.227 -04:00 [DBG] No information found on request to perform content negotiation.
2023-06-01 10:47:56.228 -04:00 [DBG] Attempting to select an output formatter without using a content type as no explicit content types were specified for the response.
2023-06-01 10:47:56.228 -04:00 [DBG] Attempting to select the first formatter in the output formatters list which can write the result.
2023-06-01 10:47:56.229 -04:00 [DBG] Selected output formatter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter' and content type 'application/json' to write the response.
2023-06-01 10:47:56.230 -04:00 [INF] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[TestLogging.User, TestLogging, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.
2023-06-01 10:47:56.236 -04:00 [INF] Executed action TestLogging.Controllers.UserController.GetUsers (TestLogging) in 65.6762ms
2023-06-01 10:47:56.237 -04:00 [INF] Executed endpoint 'TestLogging.Controllers.UserController.GetUsers (TestLogging)'
2023-06-01 10:47:56.238 -04:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:7067/api/User/test - - - 200 - application/json;+charset=utf-8 105.4926ms
```

Comment: You seem to be calling `UseSerilog` twice? Is that on purpose?

Comment: @Fildor Yep, too quick on the cut/paste  - There's a number of ways to configure logging.  Serilog's GitHub page provides a nice overview https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore